# Matrix Notation: When to use subscripts vs parentheses.

Tags: matrices, notation, matrix-equations, index-notation

Does $I(m,n) = I_{m,n}$?

I was looking at the formula for the mean-square error of two image and noticed they use $m$ and $n$ inside parentheses to denote rows and columns:

$MSE=\frac{\sum_{M, N}\left[I(m, n)-\hat{I}(m, n)\right]^2}{M * N}$

My question is would the following be equivalent?

$MSE=\frac{\sum_{M, N}\left[I_{m, n}-\hat{I}_{m, n}\right]^2}{M * N}$'

Comment: What is $I(m, n)$ and $I_{m, n}$ in your notation?

Comment: People use different notations depending on where they are from, who taught them, whether one notation may interact negatively with something else appearing, and several other factors.  So long as it is clear what you mean, it doesn't matter what notation you use.  If you worry someone has not seen your specific notation before, then define it before using it.

Comment: @SeanRoberson clearly the $m$'th row $n$'th column entry of the matrix (*or perhaps reversed... again, different people - different preferences*)

Comment: The subscript notation is more common, but it's not like there is some authority that decides on what notation is allowed, you're free to use any notation you want and the one with parentheses is pretty reasonable too. It might be context-dependent -- you're talking about "images" so they might not be thinking of these as "matrices", but as simple tables. "Matrices" have a connotation with linear operators.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks this actually answers many more questions I had.